# PropertyAction after ScaleAnimator in SequentialAnimation

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

When the item goes into the "Selected" state, the animation works correctly. But when the element passes from the "Selected" state, only the ScaleAnimator is triggered.

Why does PropertyAction fail?

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    id: item

    width: 200
    height: 200

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: "red"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    onZChanged: console.log(z)

    states: State {
        name: "SELECTED"
        when: mouseArea.containsMouse
        PropertyChanges { target: rect; color: "blue" }
    }

    transitions: [
        Transition {
            to: "SELECTED"            
            SequentialAnimation {
                PropertyAction {//work fine
                    target: item
                    property: "z"
                    value: 1
                }
                ScaleAnimator {//work fine
                    target: rect
                    from: 1
                    to: 1.25
                }
            }
        },
        Transition {
            from: "SELECTED"
            SequentialAnimation {
                ScaleAnimator {//work fine
                    target: rect
                    from: 1.25
                    to: 1
                }
                PropertyAction {//not work
                    target: item
                    property: "z"
                    value: 0
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: rect
        hoverEnabled: true
    }
}
```

In logs will only change z to 1.

Comment: It works here on Qt 5.6 and 5.9

Comment: I try on Qt 5.7

Comment: It works on 5.7.1 too here

Comment: @GrecKo Z-order changed to 0?

Comment: yes, it does change to 0

Comment: @GrecKo Thank you very much!